# Rewrite URL not working correctly?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have my htaccess working correctly (confimed with other rules, mainly 'redirect 301 LINK').
What is wrong with this?

site.local/profiles/FirstName-LastName, should serve the file, /profiles/Firstname-LastName.php

RewriteRule /profiles/FirstName-LastName /profiles/FirstName-Lastname.php [L,QSA]

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^profiles/([^/\.]+)/?$ profiles/$1.php [L]
```

This is the correct way of doing it.